# Yellow leaves and brown tips on new leaves of mango tree

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, mango

My mango tree is about 3 years old. I cut off the flowers last year to allow it to grow stronger before fruiting. It is about 4 feet tall. Recently the new young leaves which appeared are yellow and the leaf tips are brown. The older more mature leaves are normal and green.
[image]

Could you please advise what is happening to my mango tree and how I can fix it please? It is planted in the ground. There may be an issue with the ground being fairly clay based. I can add photo if needed.

Answer (score 1):

New growth on Mangoes is always a different colour to the old growth foliage. Many varieties have dark red new leaves. Others have yellow that eventually turn red, and then green once matured. The browning at the end of the leaves is most likely sunburn, water well at the base in the morning and afternoon if the soil is a bit dry, not at midday. Avoid the foliage at the hotter times of the day (watering the leaves during these times will actually boil them). I also see that it is next to a fence with a lot of reflected heat. Try growing a climber or put some cloth on the fence to reduce the reflected heat, or move the mango to a better position if possible.